# c# edit excel file if print pages > 1?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel

I have a function that writes a large list of data to an excel file. It is created on the fly, with a header and title being inserted at creation rather than using an existing template. At the minute it prints out at about 6 pages, I know i can use 
    xlWorkSheet2.PageSetup.Pages.Count
to get how many pages there are, but what i'm looking to do is **detect** when there will be a new page printed, and add my header/title to the top of this page before it prints.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the header once and then use this to set the range for a header which is repeated on each subsequent page.

```
xlWorkSheet2.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"
```